# References needed to use methods

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I need to use these three methods but do not have the refereneces:

```
Base64URLDecode()
SignWithHmac()
ToURLBase64String()
```

I have been looking all over the web to find the references for them but have no luck. Does anyone know where I can (and what they are)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for [this](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=327976).